# How can i retrieve value from Map<Object,List<Object>> obj=new HashMap<Object,List<Object>>();

Tags: java

Map> obj=new HashMap>();

How to retrieve value from above Map object?

I am beginner to java kindly help me

Comment: This might be helpful. http://a4academics.com/tutorials/61-core-java/527-java-map-example-insert-and-retrieve-data

Answer (score 0):

to retrive object from HashMap you have to use method HashMap.get(Object).
The value passed to get must be same (must have same hashCode()) as value passed to HashMap.put(Object) method.

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps work on the principle of keys and values. For every key, there is a value.

If you want to get ths value associated with the key, use the `get(key)` method. This will return the value for the key or null if key does not exist.

You declaration and initialization of the map is wrong, though. It should be as follows:
`Map<Object,List<Object>> map = ...`
Since Map is an interface, you will need to use a HashMap or something in place of ... on the right side.

Please have a look : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: First of all you need to put data into the map. Have you done that ?